# How exactly can Python complement your C# skills for windows based development?

Tags: c#, python

I'm looking for a fun challenge, and am thinking about learning Python. I've heard really good things about the language. My question is, how (if at all) can Python complement the skills of a typical C# developer working mainly with MS technologies on a Windows Platform.

Some examples of typical C# dev on windows would be (SOA applications, web applications, windows services, automation, xml handling)

Surely there must be some scenarios where knowing Python would help you get certain tasks done quicker or more efficiently than using traditional C# / MS technologies.

If you know of any specific scenarios, then please share.

Comment: If you are not sure, make it community wiki.

Answer (score 4):

At first, if you don't know a dymanic, non static-typed language, it will certainly help you to learn one. You will find out new programming paradigms and will affect your coding style and even if you don't use for a proper project, there are benefits in it for you. This of course applies for any new language you learn.

Specifically for C# and Python, have a look at [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). You can use it interchangeably with C# code and select to program specific bits in it.

One interesting application will be add scripting functionality in an existing application. You can embed IronPython to it and build a scripting environment with it.

Comment: isn't non-static the same as dynamic? :)